Find number of rows per group in every 30 minute window in Big query
I have a table in Big query with the following schema :



Customer
epoc_time
attempt_id




cust_id_1
1691191261
ab1


cust_id_1
1691191263
ab2


cust_id_2
1708458074
ab3



Each row has a unique attempt_id, and I am trying to find the total attempts by each customer in every 30/60 minute window.
And I want to achieve the following output :



Customer
date and timewindow combination
total attempts in the time window




cust_id_1
2024-01-01-00.00.00
5


cust_id_2
2024-01-01-11.30.00
4



Thanks in advance for any help !

declare time_window int64 default 30;
SELECT 
customer_id,
timestamp_seconds(safe_cast(floor(epoch_time / (time_window*60) ) * ((time_window*60)) as int64)) as date_and_timewindow_combination    ,
count(distinct attempt_id) as total_attempts_in_the_time_window,
from your_table
group by 1,2;

You can divide the epoch to the interval (in unix) to achieve any desired time frame
